# Web browsers interacting with desktop?

Tags: javascript, flash, silverlight, browser, ria

What languages/techniques are used for letting the web browser interact with the desktop, e.g. dragging files to the web browser, dragging files from web browser to desktop, and maybe more features that I'm not aware of.

I think flash and silverlight allows you to do that but I'm not sure.

Does javascript do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "interact with the desktop"?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "interact". Browsers can't really interact with the desktop except for choosing files to upload or choosing places to download files. There's a good reason for that.

ActiveX controls on Windows permitted IE to interact with the desktop, which turned out to be a gigantic security nightmare. Even Microsoft has backed off of that approach now.

If you want to interact with the user's computer, you should try AIR, which is an executable application outside of the browser.

Comment: Like this: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/SL4-Desktop-Drag-and-Drop-Silver-Sky.aspx

Comment: @ajsie: It appears you have your answer. But it's not something Javascript can do, and it will only work for people who have Silverlight plugin installed — not an insurmountable obstacle, to be sure, but certainly not universal. Neither is Flash, for that matter.